# How to insert text into a text file on a specific line or after a specific word?

Tags: html, ruby, file

I need to create a method that will insert the values passed to it into the body of a index.html file immediately after the first `<body>`.

I have the code:

```rb
class New_class

  def status(sourse, hp, sleep)

    @sourse = sourse

    File.open(@sourse, 'a'){ |file| file.puts  hp, sleep }

  end
end

tamgem = New_class.new

tamgem.status("index.html", 20, 20)
```

How can I make sure the numbers that I pass to this method are inserted into the body of the HTML document? Also, please note that this is a only Ruby, not Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing HTML with regular expressions or any other primitive means like StringScanner is [seldom a good idea](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/). Instead use a HTML parser ([nokogiri](https://nokogiri.org/)) that actually understands HTML.

```
require 'nokogiri'
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body></body></html>')
@doc.at('body').add_child('<h1>Hello World</h1>')
@doc.to_html
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a method like this:

```
def write_after_body(original_file, new_file, *new_content)
  File.open(new_file, 'w') do |file|
    IO.foreach(original_file) do |line|
      file.write(line)
      if line.include? '<body>'
        file.write(*new_content)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It will leave the original file unchanged and create a new file with the changes you want because reading and writing from and to the same file at the same time isn't really a good idea. Calling the method like this:

```
write_after_body("index.html", "new_index.html", 20," ", 20)
```

Will copy all the content from the original file `index.html` to the new file `new_index.html` and also add `20`, `" "` and `20` to a new line after the `<body>` tag. After that, if you're happy with the results you can delete/move the old file and rename the new file.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a built-in class called [`StringScanner`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html), which can be used as a convenient way to find a position of some pattern inside of a string.

Why could this be useful in your case?  You can try to find the index of the first character after the `<body>` tag.

Knowing that index, you can easily insert a substring into the correct place in your HTML.

Here is an example:

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</body>
</html>
```

```
# Ruby script in the same folder as `index.html`.

# Library where StringScanner is located.
require 'strscan'

# Read all content of `index.html` and store it into a variable.
html = File.read('index.html')

# Create the StringScanner instance.
scanner = StringScanner.new(html)

# Then you are scanning your HTML string until the first occurence of the <body> tag.
scanner.scan_until(/<body>/)

# If your search is successful,
# then the scan pointer position will be just beyond the last character of the match.
# 
# In other words,
# the scan pointer position will be the index of the first character after `<body>` tag.
index = scanner.pos

# Simple insert
updated_html = html.insert(index, "\nHello")

# Write updated content to `index.html`.
File.write('index.html', updated_html)
```

So, probably your class will look like the following:

```rb
require 'strscan'

class New_class
  def status(source, hp, sleep)
    html = File.read(source)

    scanner = StringScanner.new(html)

    scanner.scan_until(/<body>/)

    index = scanner.pos

    updated_html = html.insert(index, "#{hp} #{sleep}")

    File.write(source, updated_html)
  end
end

tamgem = New_class.new

tamgem.status("index.html", 20, 20)
```

As a last note: If you don't have any special requirements, please use CamelCase for class names as it is suggested by the majority of Ruby style guides. Here are some examples: [Rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#camelcase-classes), [Airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/ruby#naming).

Sources:

1. [StringScanner](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html)
2. [String#insert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-insert)
3. [File.read](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/IO.html#method-c-read)
4. [File.write](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/IO.html#method-c-write)
5. [CamelCase Classes by Rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#camelcase-classes)
6. [CamelCase Classes by Airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/ruby#naming)

After reading this article

### Update

I agree, in general, [it is not a good idea to use regular expressions to parse HTML](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/),
so when a problem is relatively simple you can use the approach described above,
but if you need something more comprehensive, please refer to [@max answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58575627/12201472).